# Как заменить текст в ячейке C1FlexGrid при редактировании

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет!
Задача - в колонке "Пароль" в таблице отображаются звёздочки "********" вместо реального пароля. В начале редактировании ячейки пароля появляется реальный пароль и его можно править. По окончании редактирования пароля данные сохраняются, а вместо реального пароля опять появляются звёздочки. Как такое можно организовать? (C1FlexGrid - контрол ComponentOne, имеет общие с DataGrid проперти и события)
Я использую следующий код

```
<Window x:Class="TurCC.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c1="http://schemas.componentone.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<c1:C1FlexGrid
    Name="gr_CertUsers" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    SelectionMode="Row" AllowDragging="None" 
    GridLinesVisibility="All" AllowDrop="False"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CertUsersCV}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCertUser, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    CellEditEnded="gr_CertUsers_CellEditEnded"
    PrepareCellForEdit="gr_CertUsers_PrepareCellForEdit">
    <c1:C1FlexGrid.Columns>
        <c1:Column ColumnName="UserLogin" Header="Логин" 
            Binding="{Binding Login, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </c1:Column>
        <c1:Column ColumnName="UserPassword" Header="Пароль"
            Binding="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        </c1:Column>
    </c1:C1FlexGrid.Columns>
</c1:C1FlexGrid>
</Window>


private void gr_CertUsers_PrepareCellForEdit(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
{
    // думаю, здесь можно вставить в ячейку реальный пароль
}

private void gr_CertUsers_CellEditEnded(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
{
    //думаю, здесь можно вернуть звёздочки для ячейки, вместо реального пароля
}
```

Пробовал в функции gr_CertUsers_PrepareCellForEdit менять текст ячейки, но не вышло. **Как программно менять текст в момент начала редактирования ячейки и в момент окончания редактирования?**

Comment: А что такое `C1FlexGrid`? Выглядит как контрол из какой-то сторонней библиотеки.

Comment: Это контрол ComponentOne, имеет общие проперти и события с DataGrid. Немного дополнил код xaml в описании

Comment: У вас в качестве источника данных используется CertUsersCV. Там пароли в каком виде? И каким образом вы пытались менять текст ячейки?

Comment: CertUsersCV - ObservableCollection<Users>. Users - класс, содержащий  свойства UserLogin и Password типа string. Пробовал в событии PrepareCellForEdit вытянуть из свойств окна DataContext, в котором лежит моя ViewModel и коллекция CertUsersCV. Менял в коллекции значение Password, и в SelectedCertUser менял Password - в коллекции значение поменялось, а в ячейке нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша таблица "не вкурсе" изменений которые происходят в её ItemsSource. Поэтому когда вы меняли пароль в CertUsersCV изменения не отображались. При привязке данных, если желаете своевременного обновления, после внесения изменений нужно явно указывать, что сорс изменился.

Хотя в вашем случае, я бы предложил реализовать следующую схему: В класе Users свойство Password разделите на 2. Т.е. MaskedPassword и DeMaskedPassword. Где get'ер MaskedPassword при запросе возвращает DeMaskedPassword  заменяя все его символы звёздочками, а get'ер DeMaskedPassword возвращает пароль в первозданном виде. Соответственно set'ер есть только у DeMaskedPassword.

По триггеру начала редактирования пароля
меняйте  `Binding="{Binding Path=MaskedPassword` на `Binding="{Binding Path=DeMaskedPassword` у  `<c1:Column ColumnName="UserPassword"`
По тригеру завершения возвращайте назад.

Похожий вариант можно так же реализовать не на триггерах, а на событиях на которые вы подписываетесь (PrepareCellForEdit и CellEditEnded) В этом случае у класса Users должно быть некоторое булево поле, в зависимости от значения которого геттер возвращает либо маскированный пароль либо демаскированный.

Comment: Реализовал на событиях. Приведу код в следующем ответе

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал задуманное на событиях PrepareCellForEdit и CellEditEnded следующим образом

```
private void gr_CertUsers_CellEditEnded(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as TurCCVM;
    Column col = (sender as C1FlexGrid).Columns[e.Column] as Column;
    if (vm != null && vm.SelectedCertUser != null && col.ColumnName == "UserPassword")
    {
        vm.SelectedCertUser._bShowPswrd = false;
    }
}

private void gr_CertUsers_PrepareCellForEdit(object sender, CellEditEventArgs e)
{
    var vm = this.DataContext as TurCCVM;
    Column col = (sender as C1FlexGrid).Columns[e.Column] as Column;
    if (vm != null && vm.SelectedCertUser != null && col.ColumnName == "UserPassword")
    {
        vm.SelectedCertUser._bShowPswrd = true;
    }
}

public class Users : ObservableObject
{
    public string _UserName;
    public string _UserPswd;
    public bool _bShowPswrd = false;
    #region Properties
    public string Login
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
        set
        {
            _UserName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Login");
        }
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _bShowPswrd ? _UserPswd : "*******"; }
        set
        {
            _UserPswd = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }
    public bool ShowPswrd
    {
        get { return _bShowPswrd; }
        set
        {
            _bShowPswrd = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }
    #endregion Properties
}
```